# Does a deformation retraction of $X$ onto a subspace $A\subset X$ induce an isomorphism $\pi_n(X) \to \pi_n(A)$?

Tags: homotopy-theory, group-isomorphism, retraction, higher-homotopy-groups

Let's say we have a topological space $X$ and a subspace $A\subset X$. Assume $A$ is a deformation retraction of $X$. Does that imply that the induced homomorphism of the deformation retraction is an isomorphism on all $\pi_n$?

All i could find was the usual proof regarding the induced homomorphism of the inklusion $i$ on the fundamentalgroups of $X$ and $A$ respectively.

Comment: Yes. More generally, a homotopy equivalence $X\to Y$ induces an isomorphism on $\pi_n$. Try to prove it!

Comment: thanks Justin! i'll try proving it.

Comment: The most annoying part is the basepoints.

Comment: Does the proof happen to be similar to the proof we know for $n=1$? Just like to know whether the direction might be similar at least.

Comment: If you know how to deal with basepoints for $n=1$, then yes, it's similar

Comment: Please add the part how you proved it for n=1. thanks. @Zest